# Continuous functions $f,g:X\rightarrow X.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and let $f,g:X\rightarrow X$ be continuous functions such that $f(X)\cap g(X)=\emptyset$ and $f(X)\cup g(X)=X.$ Which of the following set can't equal to $X?$

$1.[0,1]$

$2.(0,1)$

$3.[0,1)$

$4.\mathbb{R}$

According to me $X$ can't equal to $[0,1]$ as if $X=[0,1]$ then both of the functions must have fixed points. But i don't know exact reason. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is compact and $f$ is continuous then $f(X)$ must be compact. Now, can you find such $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ s.t. $f(X)∩g(X)=\emptyset$ and $f(X)\cup g(X)=X$?